# Correct CSS inheritance behavior for properties that aren't inherited?

Tags: css, inheritance

So say we you have a CSS property that is not inherited by default. We'll call it "foo" and its default value is "black". Then we make the following html.

```
<div id="div1" style="foo: red;">
 <div id="div2">
   <div id="div3" style="foo: inherit;">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Since this property does not inherit by default, you'd think that in div2, "foo" must be "black" - the default value because it does not inherit by default.

But ... in div3 should the value for "foo" inherit "black" from its parent that *did not* inherit foo, or should it inherit "red" from its grandparent because its parent did not specify foo?

I need to know because I'm trying to implement something exactly to the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It inherits its parent's (not grandparent's) computed value: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the spec!

Answer (score 2):

div3 will inherit from div2, so its foo will be black. inheritance is from the parent.